# How to disable visual graph (interconnection) modifications in JGraphT/JGraphX?

Tags: java, jgrapht, jgraphx

I have visualized relationships in my program with `JGraphT`'s [`JGraphXAdapter`](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/ext/JGraphXAdapter.html).

Unfortunately, I need to allow user only visual modifications of the graph, i.e. moving/resizing nodes. But he still can edit something, despite the fact I disabled everything I found:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add( 
            new mxGraphComponent(
                jgxAdapter = new JGraphXAdapter<Corpus, CorporaDirectory.CorporaGraphEdge>(
                    CorporaDirectory.getInstance().getCorporaGraphModel()
                ) {{
                    setCellsDeletable(false);
                    setCellsCloneable(false);
                    setCellsEditable(false);
                    setCellsDisconnectable(false);

                    setConnectableEdges(false);
                    setVertexLabelsMovable(false);
                    setSplitEnabled(false);

                }}
            ) 
        );
```

specifically user still can add new edges:

[image]

**UDPATE**

If I set setEnablled(false) to `mxGraphComponent` then I get totally frozen graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `mxGraphComponent.setConnectable(false)`, it should disable connection handler in the graph component.